# Remove element if next element is the same from list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list `list1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5]`. I want to remove duplicates from the list only when the duplicate is after its original element. So in this case the output would be:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]`

I tried the following simple implementation:

```
for x in list1[:-1]:
    NextIndex = list1.index(x)+1
    if list1[NextIndex] != x:
        O.append(x)
```

But of course it won't work because i'm doing `if list1[NextIndex] != x`. I can't even use `list1.remove()`, since removing from lists while looping doesn't work. Is there any way to do that with list comprehension maybe?

Comment: How does it differentiate? They are all numbers

Comment: I believe what you are looking to use is list1.pop(indexNumber)